# When time does not run with same speed?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

When we consider a solid body or a liquid, we consider that time does run in all parts of the solid and the liquid at the same speed. What however would happen with the solid or the liquid if time does not run in all of its parts with the same value and when there are no external forces. Would the solid be destroyed?

Comment: Is the earth destroyed?

Comment: When you are standing up your feet experiences slightly greater time dilation than your head does.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are interested in the effects of gravitation within the framework of general relativity.  Significant differences in time dilation like what you suggested would be caused by extreme gravitational fields, like near a black hole.  Such an object in this situation would experience [spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification), and would be torn apart.

Comment: But what would happen, if there are just significant differences in time dilation in the body and no significant differences in gravity, which cause spaghettification?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is rigid in special relativity, but if internal forces allow some elasticity, there is no reason why the solid should break. One example is a rotating wheel. The parts of the disk farther away from the center move faster and experience a larger time dilation.